# C++ Taylor series

Tags: c++

Hi i have used this code , but it outputs me 0.00159265 instead of 0. where is the problem ?

I have used taylor's expansion to calculate sin :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;
double sin(double x)
{
       double value = x ;
       value -=(x*x*x)/6.0 ;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x)/120.0; 
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/5040.0 ;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/362880.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/39916800.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/6227020800.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/1307674368000.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/355687428096000.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/121645100408832000.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/51090942171709440000.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/25852016738884976640000.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/15511210043330985984000000.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/10888869450418352160768000000.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/8841761993739701954543616000000.0;
       return value;
}
int main()
{
 cout<<sin(3.14);
 getche();
 return 0;
}
```

Now :

I have moved my point and divergence radius between x and 3.1415 and now corrected :

```
double sin(double x)
{
       x=x-3.1415;
       double value = x ;
       value -=(x*x*x)/6.0 ;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x)/120.0; 
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/5040.0 ;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/362880.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/39916800.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/6227020800.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/1307674368000.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/355687428096000.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/121645100408832000.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/51090942171709440000.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/25852016738884976640000.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/15511210043330985984000000.0;
       value -=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/10888869450418352160768000000.0;
       value +=(x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x*x)/8841761993739701954543616000000.0;
       return value;
}
```

But it is give me reverse example : pi/2 = -1 and 3*pi/2 = 1.

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Why , no ,I want output as exactly 0 by taylor's function

Comment: FWIW, you have at least two things to learn: "exactly" is an impossible standard in numerical computation, and for series approximations you're best starting off with at most 4 or 5 terms; if you don't get close, you're probably using a poor choice of approach

Comment: The problem is not with the code, the problem is with your expectations.

Comment: ...for that matter, don't ever expect sin(3.14) to be exactly 0, since 3.14 is not exactly pi.

Comment: Actually you are outputting the correct result. The error you have is consistent with the difference between pi and 3.14.

Comment: I wish I could downvote this twice. Your second method is complete crap. The coefficients are wrong, because pi is not 3.1415.

Comment: And please consider that double arithmetic usually comes with a lot of imprecisions since you're mapping an infinite set of numbers to only 64 bit ;-)

Comment: Also consider not multiplying `x` over and over again, but instead multiplying incrementally: `term *= x / ++n;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding the updated code, your radius adjustment is incorrect. You need to shift by multiples of 2π radians. You have shifted by π radians.  To be more generally applicable your code should shift by multiples of 2π radians until it is in the range -π to π. This can be done with a single addition.

You also really should use an accurate value for π.

Comment: others are not mathematician . good for you . they just rate down.

Answer (score 6):

Why should it be exactly zero? `sin(pi)` is zero but that's not what you're computing -- you're computing an approximation of `sin(3.14)`.

Comment: power up your def math . then rate the question

Answer (score 6):

Because `sin(3.14) = 0.0015926529164868282`, and not zero.

Note that `pi - 3.14 ~ 0.0015926536...` and `sin(pi - x) ~ x`, which is consistent with your result.

Pi is not `3.14`.

Comment: In Indiana, `pi` is defined as `3.2` (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indiana_Pi_Bill).

Comment: @hochl: almost, a bill was proposed but it never got passed.

Comment: @Downvoter: please explain in what respect is this answer wrong ?

Comment: power up your def math . then rate the question

Comment: @Parckhid: I don't understand your statement. Please clarify. If you are talking about the updated question, the answer is the same. Take an accurate value for `pi` and use the fact that `sin(pi - x) = sin(x)`, as any textbook will tell you.

Answer (score 3):

Note that your expansion of `sin(x)` is poorly convergent for values of `x` with large magnitude. You should shift `x` by a multiple of `2π` such that `x` is in the range `-π` to `π`. This takes advantage of the fact that `sin` is periodic with period `2π`.

If you make such a shift you will be able to use fewer terms in your expansion.

I would also recommend writing your expansion as a `for` loop. This will make it easier for you to experiment to find out how many terms you need to gain an accurate answer.

Comment: or a completely different algorithm -- taylor series usually suck except for the neighborhood of one point

Comment: @Jason Presumably this is homework. Otherwise `sin()` is what you would do!

Comment: ...and actually, you're incorrect: the Taylor series converges for all x, it's just that you need a large number of terms.

Comment: actually going this far an order gives good precision for sin(3.14). The figures the OP gives are in fact good. But I agree with the general principle: use another method (eg. CORDIC, or Chebyshev interpolation, or even Taylor series, but with argument reduction).